IIS page always appears when I opened my website in my office, but my website runs normally in my laptop
IIS page always appears when I opened my website in my office, but my website runs normally in my laptop. Anyone can fix the problem? I want to update anything on the website only if I can access the web on my office.
I hope someone can fix the problem

You have to reveal the actual site binding(s) you set, as that's the key, https://docs.lextudio.com/jexusmanager/tutorials/binding-diagnostics#background

The issue you're experiencing likely stems from a configuration or network issue in your office environment rather than a problem with your website itself, check the web server logs to see if there are any requests coming from your office’s IP address. This can help you pinpoint where the issue might be occurring.
